# Input on Microsoft Band

Tags: microsoft-band

I know it is possible to display information on a Microsoft Band, and also possible to display buttons and react to button events.

But is there a way to get textual input from the user, something like a TextBox or at least a ComboBox? (I guess combobox-like behavior can be constructed with manually rendering multiple buttons in a scrollable layout container, but that seems very manual.)

Thank you.

György

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the Band SDK does not expose a means to obtain text from the user.  On Windows Phone, however, an application can use Cortana integration to respond to voice input from the Band.

Comment: Thank you, Phil. Is this just a temporary restriction which will be removed one day with an update, or this is a by-design long-term limitation?

Comment: I can't speak to the product team's future plans, unfortunately.  The best thing for you to do is to add or vote for the feature on the Microsoft Health and Band UserVoice page (https://microsofthealth.uservoice.com/forums/283636-microsoft-health-and-microsoft-band).